# Use Objective-C blocks in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have a third party Objective-C library in my swift project, in one of the .h files, it has a `typedef`:

`typedef void (^YDBlutoothToolContectedList) (NSArray *);`

and inside the class, it has a property:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) YDBlutoothToolContectedList blutoothToolContectedList;`

(please ignore its spelling)

When I try to use this property in my swift class, I use

```
bt.blutoothToolContectedList = {(_ tempArray: [Any]) -> Void in
    self.devices = tempArray
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and I got the error says:

`Cannot assign value of type '([Any]) -> Void' to type 'YDBlutoothToolContectedList!'`

I know the above Objective-C code in swift would be:

`typealias YDBlutoothToolContectedList = () -> Void`

but I can't re-write that Objective-C file and swift can't cast the closure type, is there a possible way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13):

```
typedef void (^YDBlutoothToolContectedList) (NSArray *);
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
public typealias YDBlutoothToolContectedList = ([Any]?) -> Swift.Void
```

because the closure parameter can be `nil`. (You can verify that
by selecting the .h-file and then choosing *Navigate->Jump to Generated Interface* in the Xcode menu.)

Therefore the 
correct assignment would be

```
bt.blutoothToolContectedList = {(_ tempArray: [Any]?) -> Void in
    // ...
}
```

or simply let the compiler infer the parameter type:

```
bt.blutoothToolContectedList = { tmpArray in
    // ...
}
```

*If* you could add a nullability annotation to the Objective-C definition:

```
typedef void (^YDBlutoothToolContectedList) (NSArray  * _Nonnull );
```

then it would be mapped to Swift as

```
public typealias YDBlutoothToolContectedList = ([Any]) -> Swift.Void
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't have much OC experience, so sometimes it's difficult for me to read some of the OC source codes and try to convert them into Swift.

Comment: @SensEyeNULL: You are welcome! Does this answer your question? Please let me know if you need more information.