# Cannot assign value of type '(Type1?, Type2?)' to type 'TypeDef' (aka '(Type1, Type2) -> ()')

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, typedef, microsoft-speech-api

I am looking at implementing a swift version of some objective C code. I have a Typedef with the declaration:

```
void (^)(Class1 * _Nonnull, Class2 * _Nonnull)
```

The class declarations are:

```
@class Class1 : NSObject;
@class Class2 : NSObject;
```

Class2 has a result property as such:

```
@property (readonly, atomic) Result * _Nullable result;
```

When trying to use this, I have the following:

Class Properties

```
var object1: Class1?
var object2: Class2?
var result: Result?
var objectTD: TypedefName?
```

and some code:

```
self.object1 = try! Class1()
self.object2 = Class2.init()
self.objectTD = (self.object1, self.object2)
self.Class1!.method(self.objectTD)
```

The errors I get for the last two lines are:

> Cannot assign value of type '(Class1?, Class2?)' to type 'TypedefName' (aka '(Class1, Class2) -> ()')
>
> Value of optional type 'TypedefName?' (aka 'Optional<(Class1, Class2) -> ()>') must be unwrapped to a value of type 'TypedefName' (aka '(Class1, Class2) -> ()')

Comment: This is actually too simple to duplicate. (Never thought I'd say that here.) Any Chance you could provide something to duplicate? That also means Obj-C code too. Be glad to try to help. And maybe in developing something I could duplicate, you might find the issue.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Can not use Objective-c block in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030325/can-not-use-objective-c-block-in-swift)

Comment: @Willeke I am not sure if the link helps, or at least I still do not understand what I need to do.

Comment: `self.object1` and `self.object2` are defined as optionals and should be unwrapped before assign to `TypeDef`.

Comment: Are you familiar with Objective-C blocks? Maybe this helps: [Use Objective-C blocks in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460650/use-objective-c-blocks-in-swift) or search the Internet to find out how to use Objective-C blocks in Swift.